# Which of these Attempted Proofs for Discontinuity is Correct and Why?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, continuity

**Question:**

Let $f$:$R$$\to R$  be defined by the formula $f(x) = sin(1/x)$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$ when $x$ is irrational. Show that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x = 0.$

**Attempt 1:**

Since $\lim_{x \to 0^+}sin(1/x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-}sin(1/x)$ do not exist, then $f$ is discontinuous at $x = 0.$

**Attempt 2:**

For $\epsilon$ $= 1/2$, there exists no $\delta$ $>0$ such that $|f(x) - f(0)|$ $<$ $\epsilon$  whenever $|x|<$ $\delta$ because every neighbourhood of zero contains infinitely many irrationals. Hence, $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x = 0.$

**Attempt 3:**

We can find a sequence $x_{n}$ which converges to zero but $limf$$($$x_{n}$$)$ $\neq$ $f(0) = 0.$

**What I think about Each of the Attempted Proofs**

I think **Attempt 3** is wrong since $f(0)$ does not exist in the first place. We can calculate $f(0)$ from the formula $f(x) = sin(1/x)$ since $x = 0$ here (and $0$ is rational). Since $1/x$ is not defined at $x = 0,$ then $sin(1/x)$ will not be defined at $x = 0$. This means $f(0)$ does not exist. So, the proof could have been something along this line: ***We know $f(0)$ is required to exist for a function $f$ to be continuous at $0$. We say $f$ is not continuous at $0$ since $f(0)$ does not exist.*** However, I still feel I am mixing things up here.

I am more confident about **Attempt 1** than I am of **Attempt 2**. The later is an adapted solution from a similar question that investigates the discontinuity of $f$ at $x = 0,$ where $f(x) = 1$ when $x$ is rational and $0$ when $x$ is irrational. My doubt for **Attempt 2** stems from my struggle to *really* understand the reason I gave:***'...because every neighbourhood of zero contains infinitely many irrationals'***. This reason is fairly common in solutions to problems of this type in the textbooks I have seen. What does this reason *really* mean? How does it support the argument in the proof? Does it mean whenever we consider the rationals in a neighbourhood of $0$, the irrationals interfere, and vice versa? Please help me understand what is going on here.

Please help me shed light on these solutions. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $f$ is not defined at $x=0,$ so it can’t be continuous there. However, you’ve shown (or outlined how to show) that it can’t be defined at $0$ to make it continuous.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews can you help me with my struggle with the phrase, '...because every neighbourhood of zero contains infinitely many irrationals'?

Comment: Not until you define $f(0).$ A function is neither continuous nor discontinuous at points where it is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is nonsensical since

$$f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \qquad x \mapsto \begin{cases}
\sin(1/x) & x \in \Bbb Q \\
0 & x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

is not even defined at zero (so really it's a function $f : \Bbb R \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb R$). For continuity to hold we require that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$$

In particular then we cannot be continuous at a point outside of the domain of the function.

---

Ignoring this particular issue rendering all three attempts problematic (after all, you could just redefine $f(0)$ to be whatever you please, it won't matter in the end), I'd also note that:

- **Attempt $\#1$:** This works fine enough, though it would need some rigorization. You could take sequences of points $x_n \in \Bbb Q$ where $x_n \to 0$ from either side, and consider that $\sin(1/x_n)$ does not exist in the limit.
- **Attempt $\#2$:** The (other) issue is not that each neighborhood of $0$ has infinitely many **ir**rationals, but infinitely many rationals, and in particular $\sin(1/x)$ achieves its extreme values of $\pm 1$ infinitely many times for $x$ in a neighborhood of zero. The irrationals give $0$ as a possible candidate for the limiting process.
- **Attempt $\#3$:** This attempt would be fine in theory ... but hard to manage in practice since the "obvious" candidates for such a sequence are the points where $\sin(1/x)$ achieves a maximum or minimum, but
  $$\sin \frac 1 x = \pm 1 \implies x = \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{2}{4n \pm 1} , n \in \Bbb Z$$
  and so these are not at rational points. Using $\sin(\pi/x)$ would nullify that of course, however.

Comment: For attempt #3, instead of the maximum, one could identify intervals of the form $[a,b]$ where $sin(1/a)=\sin(1/b)=\frac12$ and $\sin(1/x)>\frac12$ for $a<x<b$; then choose a rational $x$ in the interval $[a,b].$

Comment: @Eevee Trainer I think Attempt #2 is clearer to me now. Also, I never imagined the concerns you raised about Attempt #1 and 3. I learned a lot from your post.

Comment: @David K it seems the argument you are making is $sin(1/x)$ should not be greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ or is it mean that is not getting it?

Comment: @abc The point is you can construct a sequence of rational $x$ such that $\sin(1/x)$ either does not converge as $x\to0$ or it converges to something other than $0.$ It occurs to me, however, that I may have invoked the axiom of choice. I think what this really leads back to is some version of attempt #1 as explained in the answer.

Comment: @David K I think I get it now. Thanks for your time.